# How to add dynamic elements to an existing form

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I want to add additional elements to an existing form in Xamarin and change existing elements on the existing form. Here is the code of the element needs to be added to existing form right before the button `Name = "GenerateBtn"`:

```
Entry accNumber = new Entry()
{
   Text = "number"
};
```

Could I add specifically to RelativeLayout or is the StackLayout enough? Here is xaml file:

```
    <StackLayout 
            x:name = "First"
            VerticalOptions ="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">

       <Entry
            Text="First name"/>
        <Entry
            Text="Last name"/>

          <RelativeLayout
                x:Name = "cardInfo"
                VerticalOptions ="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"
                RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Y, Factor=0, Constant=220}" 
                HeightRequest="60" 
                RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1}" >

         <Button 
            x:Name = "Account"
            Text="account" 
            Clicked="Handle_Clicked"
            HeightRequest="50"
            WidthRequest="120"
            RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Y, Factor=0, Constant=5}" 
            RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=X, Factor=0, Constant=5}"/> 

          <Button
            x:Name = "Btn2"
            Text="button2" 
            Clicked="Handle_Clicked"
            HeightRequest="50"
            WidthRequest="120"
            RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Y, Factor=0, Constant=5}" 
            RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0.5, Constant=5}" />

       </RelativeLayout>
        <Button 
            x:Name = "GenerateBtn"
            Text="Generate" 
            Clicked="Handle_Clicked"/>

     </StackLayout>
```

Comment: Why don't you do it like everyone else just add anything with IsVisible="False" then set it to true when condition is met... By binding or by code behind as you like.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap `Button(Name = "GenerateBtn")` inside `StackLayout` first ,and  then add `Entry` as child view into Stacklayout.

#### In Xmal

```
<StackLayout x:Name="stack" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Button  x:Name = "GenerateBtn" Text="Generate"/>
</StackLayout>
```

#### Code behind

```
stack.Children.Insert(0,new Entry { Text = "number" });
```